Создаю телеграм-бота на Python с помощью библиотеки telebot. Бот будет пересылать пять последних сообщений из Telegram-канала при нажатии кнопки
Бот должен пересылать пять последних сообщений из телеграм-канала в переписку с пользователем при нажатии кнопки. После нажатия на кнопку "Ещё" будут отправляться следующие пять постов, и так до тех пор, пока посты не закончатся. Сообщения могут содержать фотографии, музыкальные файлы, файлы разных форматов и видео. Я искал информацию везде, даже спрашивал у ChatGPT, но не нашел решения. Ранее на форуме мне посоветовали использовать "bot.get_history", но такой функции нет. Я знаю, что можно использовать базу данных, но хотел бы обойтись без неё. Если это невозможно, подскажите, как оптимально реализовать это с базой данных.

пожалуйста, не плодите дубликаты вопроса, удаляя заодно и написанные вам комментарии и ответы: 1 и 2.
